# addPresentedHandler not being triggered in Metal on iOS

Tags: ios, metal, objective-c++

I've been trying to set up a `addPresentedHandler` for some time now, but without luck.

I've got a `addCompletedHandler` working on the command buffers that contain the rendering work to be executed every frame. I've verified that the `addCompletedHandler` is working by seeing setting breakpoints within the code block. These are triggered when running the app. For the `addPresentedHandler` however, no breakpoint within the code block is triggered (I've also verified through modifying variables from the code block, and inserting `printf`s into the block).

My rendering loop is currently very simple, and looks like this (hopefully I've provided enough):

NOTE: I'm using a strong combination of C++ and Objective-C++. The code presented below is therefore not a direct representation of the actual code.

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(m_inFlightFramesSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
m_drawables[m_currentFrameIndex] = [m_swapChain nextDrawable];
MTLRenderPassDescriptor* renderPassDescriptor = [MTLRenderPassDescriptor new];
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = m_drawables[m_currentFrameIndex].texture;
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].level = 0;
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].slice = 0;
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = MTLStoreActionStore;
renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [m_commandQueue commandBuffer];
id<MTLRenderCommandEncoder> renderEncoder = [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor: renderPassDescriptor];
[renderEncoder setRenderPipelineState: m_pipelineState];
[renderEncoder setTriangleFillMode: MTLTriangleFillModeFill];
[renderEncoder setFrontFacingWinding: MTLWindingCounterClockwise];
[renderEncoder setCullMode: MTLCullModeBack];
/* set viewport and scissor (omitted here) */
[renderEncoder useResource: m_vertexBuffer usage: MTLResourceUsageRead stages: MTLRenderStageVertex];
[renderEncoder setVertexBuffer: m_vertexBuffer offset: 0 atIndex: 0];
[renderEncoder useResource: m_indexBuffer usage: MTLResourceUsageRead stages: MTLRenderStageVertex];
[renderEncoder drawIndexedPrimitives: MTLPrimitiveTypeTriangle indexCount: 6
  indexType: MTLIndexTypeUInt32 indexBuffer: m_indexBuffer indexBufferOffset: 0
  instanceCount: 1];
[renderEncoder endEncoding];
PresentDrawable(commandBuffer, m_drawables[m_currentFrameIndex]);
CommitFinalCommandBufferInFrame(commandBuffer);
```

The two final function calls are implemented as follows:

```
void PresentDrawable(id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer, id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable)
{
    [drawable addPresentedHandler:^(id<MTLDrawable> dr) {
        m_framesPresented++;
        if (m_framesPresented == m_maxFrames)
        {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(m_lastFramePresentedSemaphore);
        }
    }];

    [commandBuffer presentDrawable:drawable];
}

void CommitFinalCommandBufferInFrame(id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer)
{
    [commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> cb) {
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(m_inFlightFramesSemaphore);
    }];

    [commandBuffer commit];
    m_framesSubmitted++;
    m_currentFrameIndex = (m_currentFrameIndex + 1) % m_maximumDrawableCount;
}
```

I don't see why the `addPresentedHandler` code block isn't be triggered, while the `addCompletedHandler` block is...am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my question, I did not mention that I was running on the iPhone 11 Pro Max (v13.3) Simulator. Upon trying on an actual iPhone 11 (v13.3.1) the `addPresentHandler` as implemented in my question triggers successfully. I've tried to determine if this limitation in functionality on the simulator is documented anywhere, but have come up empty.

As specified in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldrawable/2806858-addpresentedhandler?language=objc), `addPresentedHandler` requires version iOS version 10.3. This is also reflected in it's definition in *MTLDrawable.h*:

```
- (void)addPresentedHandler:(MTLDrawablePresentedHandler)block
                             API_AVAILABLE(ios(10.3))
                             API_UNAVAILABLE(macos, macCatalyst);
```

Nowhere can I find any mention of limitations for the simulator version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems with your code, I've checked it works.

```
void PresentDrawable(id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer, id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable)
{
    [drawable addPresentedHandler:^(id<MTLDrawable> dr) {

        printf("Handler \n");
        m_framesPresented++;
        if (m_framesPresented == m_maxFrames)
        {
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(m_lastFramePresentedSemaphore);
        }
    }];

    [commandBuffer presentDrawable:drawable];
}
```

Comment: Hmm...I'll have to double check it yet again then. Thanks for verifying.